# Finding cause of Netty disconnect and connection failure events

Tags: netty

I'd like to get the reason - error code or Throwable - for TCP disconnects (failing to connect or live connection closing) when using Netty.

1. When channel fails to connect, the specific exception can be found by subscribing to the future returned by `Bootstrap.connect()`. Is that exception somehow available through Channel itself? If possible, I'd like to keep error handling in `ChannelHandler` but its `channelInactive` method does not report a cause.
2. If live channel disconnects, is it possible to get the reason (closed by remote side, locally via `close()`, killed by OS etc)?